# Como intercalar 2 digitos en cadenas de 6 digitos con expresiones regulares

Tags: regex

tengo una columna con una serie de números de 6 dígitos y necesito intercalar a 2 ceros a partir de la 3 posición:

484783 -> 48400783
653923 -> 65300923
etc..
He provado con \d{4}+00
pero creo que estoy muy lejos me podéis ayudar por favor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar en un grupo las tres primeras cifras del número, y todas las cifras restantes en otro grupo. Luego usas esos grupos en la cadena de sustitución.

Es decir, la expresión regular sería:

```
\b(\d{3})(\d+)\b
```

Y la cadena de sustitución sería:

```
$100$2
```

Pues `$1` se expandirá al primer grupo, y `$2` al segundo.

[Demo funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/uXOS5H/2)

**Nota**: la sintaxis de la cadena de reemplazo puede variar según el lenguaje de programación que uses. En python o PHP podría ser `\g<1>00\g<2>`, por ejemplo.